# Excel VBA.Program Event:=ActiveCell, Image:=Visible

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel 2000 and need assistance in programming an image to toggle between visible and hidden when a cell is active *or* a simulation of that event.

Given a list of five items in `column A`, a separate image is associated with each item. On opening the file all images should be hidden except in the event the file is open with one of the items actively selected. As the user clicks or cursors up/down `column A` the image shown changes to the associated image.

I can easily do this in other programs/languages but I am restricted to Excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can trap worksheet level events in the code module behind the worsheet. Right click the sheet tab, View code, and paste the following

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim sPic As String

    On Error GoTo errExit
    Me.Pictures.Visible = False ' hides ALL pictures
    If Not Intersect(Range("A1:A5"), Target(1)) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Target.Address(0, 0)
        Case "A1": sPic = "Picture 1"
        Case "A2": sPic = "Picture 2"
        Case "A3": sPic = "Picture 3"
        Case "A4": sPic = "Picture 4"
        Case "A5": sPic = "Picture 5"
        End Select
    Me.Pictures(sPic).Visible = True
End If

errExit:

End Sub
```

Adjust the names of your images to suit. To see the image name select it and look at the "Names" box left of the input bar.

Clsoe the VBE (visual basic editor) when done. You many need to adjust your macro security settings.